# minikube on windows 10 pro

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I had a system crash while doing install of minikube, now when i try to do a reinstall i get these errors, I've tried multiple times, but with no joy. I'm running a win 10 pro and running minikube on hyper-v

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "minikube"
I1115 23:15:25.021752    9724 translate.go:89] Failed to load translation file for en: Asset translations/en.json not found
* minikube v1.15.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19041 Build 19041
* Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Stopping node "minikube"  ...
* Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...
* Deleting "minikube" in hyperv ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
E1115 23:21:42.381763    9724 main.go:115] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3
+ ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM

E1115 23:21:54.691730    9724 main.go:115] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3
+ ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM


E1115 23:21:56.716776    9724 main.go:115] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3
+ ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
```

The VM exists and i can send a command to stop the vm, which works, but whe  i start the vm it just hangs at

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start
I1115 23:25:18.265723   16180 translate.go:89] Failed to load translation file for en: Asset translations/en.json not found
* minikube v1.15.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19041 Build 19041
* Using the hyperv driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Restarting existing hyperv VM for "minikube" ...
```

Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

rather than running this command

minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "vswitch"

I just ran this

minikube start –driver=hyperv

Answer (score 0):

`-vm-driver` is [deprecated flag](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/6888), since [minikube 1.8.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-180---2020-03-06) `--driver` flag has been introduced and should be used.

`Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube"` error might be caused by different misconfigurations, most commonly it is due to incorrect virtual switch configuration, which should be configured as `external`.

Additionally to deal with this issue I would recommend to delete content of `C:/users/<user>/.minikube` and run `minikube delete --all --purge` to clean up everything and then start minikube cluster.

Also check this [github issue's comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1967#issuecomment-364026979).